# Удаление всех Ellipse на Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеются эллипсы на `Canvas`:

```
void Ellipses(double x, double y)
{
    var e = new Ellipse()
    {
        Height = 10,
        Width = 10,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(124, 109, 177)),
        Name ="A"
    };
    canvas.Children.Add(e);
    Canvas.SetLeft(e, x - 5);
    Canvas.SetBottom(e, y - 5);
    list.Add(e);
}
```

Хочу их удалить. Но проблема в том, что он удаляет не все, а как то пропускает их через одного

```
void DeleteEllipse()
{
    //foreach (UIElement item in canvas.Children)
    //{
    //    if (item is Ellipse)
    //        canvas.Children.Remove(item);
    //}
    for (int i = 0; i < canvas.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        if (canvas.Children[i] is Ellipse)
            canvas.Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Почему эллипсы удаляется через один или через два?

Comment: `for (int i = canvas.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`

Comment: а почему на уменьшение цикл

Comment: да спасибо удаляет но в чем разница

Comment: Возьмите лист бумаги и карандаш, и для простого случая - например, три эллипса в списке - напишите, как меняются содержимое списка и счетчик в цикле.

Comment: @Igor: Тогда уж `while (canvas.Children.Count > 0) canvas.Children.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: @VladD да, и товарищ так никогда и не узнает "в чем разница"

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего не возиться с индексами, с риском ошибиться, а удалить всех одним махом:

```
canvas.Children.Clear();
```

---

Если не-эллипсы нужно оставить, попробуйте так:

```
foreach (var el in canvas.Children.OfType<Ellipse>().ToList())
    canvas.Children.Remove(el);
```

`ToList` важен.

Comment: ну у меня там еще пару Image а их удалять нельзя

Comment: @Санитариум: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Санитариум Вам уже помог ответ или надо что-то ещё?